# How to iterate over tree with memory limit in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, memory, iterator, binary-tree

I know that there is a solution for iterating through the `Tree` using `Zipper`s (see details [here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/zippers)). Though it is not clear for me whether it is possible to apply memory constraints to this approach.

### Context

I was given the following problem to solve in Haskell:

> Design an iterator that will iterate through a binary tree in-order.
>
> Assume the binary tree is stored on disk and can contain up to 10 levels, and therefore can contain up to (2^10 - 1) nodes, and we can store at most 100 nodes in memory at any given time.
>
> The goal of this iterator is to load a small fraction of the binary tree from disk to memory each time it's incremented, so that we don't need to load the entire tree into
> memory all at once.

I assumed that the memory part is not possible to represent in Haskell, but I was told that it is not true.

**Question:** what can be used in Haskell to achieve that memory behaviour? Any suggestions, approaches and directions are appreciated. This is just out of curiosity, I've already failed at solving this problem.

Comment: To write an actual answer would require a ton more details; this can't be the entire problem, can it? By "at most 100 nodes in memory," do they mean "at most 100 nodes reachable by GC" (because the rest will be deallocated as needed) or is it more harsh? In the worst case, I suppose, you can just mutate an array in-place to avoid allocation?

Comment: I don't require to write the answer to the concrete problem (which is, of course, I don't mind). I'm more interested in the approaches that could be used to work with the memory limits and allocations on demand in Haskell. 

And answering your question this is the whole task and no more details were given to me.

Comment: It feels strange because (being a GCd language) you don't have precise control over when / where memory is (de)allocated. There is some capacity for manual memory management, particularly for use with FFI eg. https://ro-che.info/articles/2017-08-06-manage-allocated-memory-haskell. As your traversal in particular is possible with (depth) nodes in memory, then you could write your own stack-based traversal with manual allocation (I suppose) which would fulfil your requirements.

Comment: The question is IMHO ill-posed. Suppose a tree is stored on disk as a text file in-order. Then I don't even need to keep more than one node at a time in main memory, I just copy the file as is. Now if it is stored as a pre-order or a post-order, how would you do what is asked in any language?

Answer (score 3):

If the iterator loads part of the tree each time it is incremented then there are two options:

1. It exists in the IO monad and works just like in an imperative language.
2. It is exploiting laziness and interleaved IO. This is the approach taken by functions like `readFile` which give you the entire contents of a file as one lazy list. The actual file is read on-demand as your application traverses the list.

The latter option is the interesting one here.

The tricky part of lazy lists is retainers. Suppose your file contains a list of numbers. If you compute the sum like this

```
nums <- map read . lines <$> readFile "numbers.txt"
putStrLn $ "The total is " <> show (sum nums)
```

then the program will run in constant space. But if you want the average:

```
putStrLn $ "The average is " <> show (sum nums / fromIntegral (length nums))
```

then the program will load the entire file into memory. This is because it has to traverse the list twice, once to compute the sum and once to compute the length. It can only do this by holding the entire list.

(The solution is to compute the sum and length in parallel within one pass. But that's beside the point here).

The challenge for the tree problem you pose is to come up with an approach to iteration which avoids retaining the tree.

Lets assume that each node in the file contains offsets in the file for the left and right child nodes. We can write a function in the IO monad which seeks to an offset and reads the node there.

```
data MyNode = MyNode Int Int .....  -- Rest of data to be filled in.

readNodeData :: Handle -> Int -> IO MyNode
```

From there it would be simple to write a function which traverses the entire file to create a `Tree MyNode`. If you implement this using [`unsafeInterleaveIO`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises) then you can get a tree which is read lazily as you traverse it.

`unsafeInterleaveIO` is unsafe because you don't know when the IO will be done. You don't even know what order it will happen in, because it only happens when the value is forced during evaluation. In this way its like the "[promise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises)" structures you get in some other languages. In this particular case this isn't a problem because we can assume the file doesn't change during the evaluation.

Unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem because the entire tree will be held in memory by the time you finish. Your traversal *has* to retain the root, at least as long as its traversing the left side, and as long as it does so it will retain the whole of the rest of the tree.

The solution is to rewrite the IO part to return a list instead of a tree, something like this:

```
readNode :: Handle -> Int -> IO [MyNode]
readNode _ (-1) = return []      -- Null case for empty child.
readNode h pos = unsafeInterleaveIO $ do
    n <- readNodeData h pos   -- Needs to be defined elsewhere.
    lefts <- readNode (leftChild n)
    rights <- readNode (rightChild n)
    return $ lefts ++ [n] ++ rights
```

This returns the entire tree as a lazy list. As you traverse the list the relevant nodes will be read on demand. As long as you don't retain the list (see above) your program will not need to hold anything more than the current node and its parents.